# WPF AutoCompleteBox Data Virtualization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, autocompletebox, data-virtualization

I am trying to implement Data Virtualization on a WPF AutoCompleteBox.
I found Bea Stollnitz's code [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=378) which works great on a ListView and I made it to work on an ComboBox easily, but there's no way I can seem to get it working right on an AutoCompleteBox.

To be precise, it works - the list is virtualized, items are not all loaded on startup - but what seems to happen is that the AutoCompleteBox iterates through all the items in the list as soon as the ItemsSource changes and this ends up breaking the whole thing (i.e. on load, all the pages in the list are requested, so even though they are virtualized, they will all be requested in the beginning and get loaded). My guess is that this is because of the filtering that the ACBox does, but I'm surprised that there's not way to prevent it, since the control does normally allow filtering to be done on the server-side using the Populating event.

I feel that I'm missing something, I can't believe that no one has done something like this before or that it can't be done, so I'm guessing that I'm just doing something obviously wrong that I can't figure out since I'm new to WPF.

Here's some of the things that I've done to try and get this together (based on Internet searches around similar problems):

- I made sure all the conditions for the built-in UI virtualization are ok including explicitly turning it on, setting the max height of the ListBox etc.
- I replaced the ListBox in the AutoCompleteBox with a ListView like the one that Bea uses in her example. Side by side, the ListView by itself works as expected, but the one embedded in the ACBox does not.
- I tried using no filtering in the ACBox, using a custom filter, handling the populating evenet manually etc. This doesn't help. Making a custom filter is obviously not enough since the custom filter only allows you to specify the result of evaluating one item, the code that loops through the list is not visible so you can't prevent looping. Turning the filter to "None" doesn't do anything either.

Any and all suggestions are welcome!

The target for this is .NET 3.5 and I am using the WPF Toolkit (Feb 2010 release)

Thank you!

Comment: Note: Weirdly enough (though it seems unrelated), UI virtualization didn't work until I had set the MaxHeight of the ListBox/View in C# code. When I had it previously set in XAML, it didn't work. But this didn't help the main issue.

Comment: May i know how you were able to make that work with Combobox? Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: @Signcodeindie It's fairly straightforward, I just worked from Bea's example with the listbox. At the most basic, you just assign the AsyncVirtualizingCollection to the ItemsSource of the ComboBox, which will work, but you need a bit more styling to really make it look&feel right (but you can almost just copy/paste the style in her example). If you're having some problems with it, maybe a good thing to do is to open up a new question to get help on that.

Comment: Note: the link to Stollnitz's blog is not working anymore; the blog posts have been moved to Github pages, so the new link should probably be: https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/52-DataVirtualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked this down to OnItemsSourceChanged() (see [source](http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40156#1144733)). In there, the AutocompleteBox stores a "local cached copy of the data", which is why I see the behavior noted above. 
This is a private method, so no overriding here.

It seems to me that because of this you can't apply DataVirtualization to the AutoCompleteBox, at least not using the ideas in Bea's solution. If anyone has any different thoughts regarding this, I would love to try it out, but until then, this is what I believe the answer to be.